# Can’t become Thane of Falkreath

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So I was achievement hunting Skyrim, and I have to buy 3 plots of land for one of the achievements. Dawnstar, Morthal, and Falkreath. I have to help citizens of all 3 of these holds. One citizen, “Hert”, is a citizen that works at Half Moon Mill. To help her, you must chop wood. However, for the Dawnguard quest line, I was required to kill her. I’ve saved up a little over 100,000 Gold on my current save, I’ve fully upgraded the Dawnstar home, and I’m at level 62. I killed Hert around level 13. So I don’t want to make another save just for 1 achievement. Is there anyway to become Thane of Falkreath if Hert is dead?

Comment: There should be more quests available for other characters in Falkreath. I never helpd Hert and always managed to get it.

Comment: Related [Is it possible to become Thane of Falkreath without completing the main quests or the civil war quests?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40671/is-it-possible-to-become-thane-of-falkreath-without-completing-the-main-quests-o)

Answer (score 3):

At [this](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane_of_Falkreath) page there is a list of quests available in Falkreath which can help you to become a Thane.

The most easy ones in my opinion:

- Deliver Berit's Ashes to Runil
- Find Runil's Journal inside a random dungeon
- Get paid to gather crops

Then there is still the quest where you steal the Private Letter for Dengeir. So in total there are 5 quests, with Hert dead, that is still 4 quests left to help you become a Thane.

Also investing gold in the shops counts toward this, which makes it really easy for you with 100k in your pocket.

So check your quest journal and see which quests you haven't done yet. (I think crops and wood chopping is not listed)

Comment: So after racking up my Speech to get the investment perk, finding a shop to invest in, and searching online for a week. After finally getting thane. I found the quest for Dengier in my Misc. Quest list

Comment: @LiamHutson Hooray! So you were able to become a thane after all?

Comment: @LiamHutson I believe that the outcome of that quest also determines who will be Jarl of Falkreath, that might be important.