# What is the benefit of being Thane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Related to this question:  [How do I become a Thane?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36839/how-do-i-become-a-thane)

For at least one of the locations you need to buy a house before you can become Thane, so what is the benefit of becoming a Thane?

Comment: For at least Riften, Solitude, and Markarth you have to buy the house before you can become Thane.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Thane, you'll have a Housecarl appointed who can act as your companion. Additionally, the guards can be convinced to overlook a variety of crimes if reminded of your station.

You'll also be given a pretty decent levelled magic weapon on being named Thane.

Comment: Does the "convincing" only work once per city, or is their some sort of time limit on it?

Comment: @VanBuzzKill yes only for once in each hold.

Answer (score -3):

You will receive the privilege of buying a house in some cities, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Actually, buyinng a house is generally a *requirement* for becoming a Thane, not the other way around.

Comment: This is true only for Whiterun!

Comment: Everybody knows that so -2.