# Elisif's Tribute - Where is the shrine of Talos?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to become Thane of Haafingar hold/ Solitude.

I cleared out Wolfskull cave, Elisif asked me to take her Husband's War Horn to a shrine of Talos. It shows up as a Misc Journal entry.

Where is this shrine?

I tried taking it to the shrine in Whiterun where the priest was always yelling. No luck, no options to leave the horn there.

I tried following this [Guide](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elisif%27s_Tribute), I kept and kept on searching. Nothing between north of ritual stone or east of Whiterun resembles what they are talking about. But it is a radiant quest so I think that information might be dated.

[This](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Becoming_Thane) guide says to go to the appropriate shrine.

Our very own [guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36839/how-do-i-become-a-thane) has no such mention, meaning it should be an easy do.

I have been wandering looking for this shrine for almost 2 hours now real time.

Which shrine of Talos do I need to drop the horn? And more importantly where is it/ How to find it?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the quest to activate it, then pressing M to have it show you the quest on the map?  It should lead you right there.

Comment: Make sure the quest is active in Miscellaneous, and make sure that Miscellaneous is active itself. Then you should see a map marker for it. For me, I was standing on top of a rock, supposedly directly at the marker. I was confused, annoyed, and decided to drop down from the rock and move on. I dropped down to discover that the rock was the top of a small cave. Inside the cave was the shrine. Too easy.

Comment: You can activate-click them in the miscellaneous list, too.

Comment: @desaivv you can navigate to the right list, guess with right-arrow-key or `D`-key but definitely with mouseclick. _(See my answer for a new image of the shrine)_

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's very hard to find, and the shrine doesn't have its own world marker, but it's there, east of *Whiterun* under a ledge:

[image: Image of shrine]

[image: Shrine location]

---

[image]

Comment: I found it so easy to find thanks to your instructions man ... cheers

Comment: It may not have a world marker, but it does have a quest indicator.