# How do I leave Torygg's War Horn at the Shrine of Talos?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm working on the following miscellaneous quest:

> Take Torygg's War Horn to the Shrine of Talos for Elisif the Fair

I have [arrived at the destination](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41048/17179), but I cannot figure out how to get the war horn out of my inventory and leave it at the shrine.

Activating the Shrine of Talos gives me Talos' Blessing, but doesn't leave the horn. I cannot seem interact with the great statue of Talos in any way. Since it is a quest item, I cannot drop the horn on the altar or on the ground in front of it, and for the same reason I cannot leave the horn in the satchel on the altar.

How do I leave Torygg's War Horn at the Shrine of Talos?

Comment: Where are you aiming when you try to drop the horn?

Comment: I've got the same bug. I can stand on the pedestal and aim at the statue or the shrine or anywhere around the area and I can't drop the item.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the quest/item is not bugged, there is a spot near the other items that have been placed in front of the Shrine of Talos where you get a note on the screen to press a key (depending on your keyboard configuration) to place the horn at the shrine. It seems to be a reasonably small spot to trigger this as it took me a couple of minutes to find it and then move slowly enough where the message would trigger and I could stop my movement in time to keep it there.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this as well and ended up using the console commands

```
player.drop 000e77bb 1
```

to drop the horn, and then

```
SetStage SolitudeFreeform07 20
```

to advance the quest.

Answer (score 0):

If u have a follower ask the follower to interact with it.
worked for me , hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to drop it either. I went and talked to Elisif again and it activated the quest again. I was able to drop it after