# What are the locations of all the purchasable houses in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I understand that the first purchasable house is in Whiterun. I want to know what other houses are buyable in the game and what cities/towns they are located in.
I would also like to know their order of appearance or availability.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36839/how-do-i-become-a-thane

Comment: There order of appearance is completely based on which one you want to travel to first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Location are: Whiterun, Riften, Markarth, Windhelm and Solitude. For more Information see: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses

Answer (score 9):

In order from least expensive to most expensive:

1. Whiterun: Breezehome
2. Riften: Honeyside
3. Markarth: Vlindrel Hall
4. Windhelm: Hjerim
5. Solitude: Proudspire Manor

Comment: Also, you have to get in good with the local Jarl. Here is the gold amount you'll need to get the house and all of the extras: (6,250g), (12,200g), (12,200g), (21,000g), (36,000g) in the same order that Nappa82 provided.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the 'Hearthfire' DLC installed you can build your own houses from scratch and there is a house or land available in every hold, exept Winterhold. if you do a special quest for the jarl in that region, in addition if you have the 'Dragonborn' DLC installed you can also earn a house in Soltheim if you help the Dunmer house reverin.

Answer (score 3):

- Whiterun
- Solstiem
- Riften
- Solitude
- Winterhold
- Dawnstar
- Morthal
- Markarth
- Falkreath
- Windhelm

These are all of the places you can buy homes.

Comment: Hi @Aidan, this answer may be correct, but it could use some better formatting.  Right now its kind of difficult to read this answer.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I  would have, but I don't know the different locations in skyrim having never played it and as such, I didn't know where to separate them.