# Houses in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the locations of all the purchasable houses in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41397/what-are-the-locations-of-all-the-purchasable-houses-in-skyrim)

I know you can buy a house in whiterun, but I cant buy one there anymore after taking over the city. What other city offers the chance to buy a house?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! There is also a house in Solitude and one in Markhart but when you have cleared Whiterun you can still buy the house. I think you have to ask for work to finished for the Jarl to get the steward offering you the house for the Jarl. Just try again and ask for work.